# mysql sum from two databases

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT  db1.table.listener, 
        db2.table.listener, 
        SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( db2.table.time ) ) + ( TIME_TO_SEC( db1.table.time ) ) ), 
        count( db2.table.listener )
FROM    table
   INNER JOIN db2.table 
        ON db1.table.listener = db2.table.listener
WHERE db2.table.ldate = '19.02.2013'
   AND db1.table.ldate = '19.02.2013'
GROUP BY db2.table.listener, db1.table.listener
```

I have two tables in two different databases with same columns (listener,time,ldate). I need to sum times and group by listener. This query gives multiple records, i need only "listener, total time, number of listens". How can i do this with one query?

Desired result;

```
| listeners (from both table, full join) | count of values (from both table) | sum of time (from both table) |
```

Comment: can you show us the desired result you wish to achieve ?

Comment: Is the listeners are INT ?

Comment: @GilPeretz no, varchar, they are names. time is varchar too.

Answer (score 0):

See following:

```
SELECT  db1.table.listener, 
        SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( db2.table.time ) ) + 
           ( TIME_TO_SEC( db1.table.time ) ) ), 
        count( db1.table.listener )
FROM    table
   INNER JOIN db2.table 
        ON db1.table.listener = db2.table.listener

WHERE db1.table.ldate = '19.02.2013'

GROUP BY db1.table.listener
```

Comment: It gives wrong values when i check it with; `SELECT listener, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ), count(listener) FROM db2.table where ldate='19.02.2013' GROUP BY listener` and `SELECT listener, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( time ) ) ), count(listener) FROM db1.table where ldate='19.02.2013' GROUP BY listener`

Comment: And i need to get both table listeners and count listener of both tables.